# Groovy: XmlSlurper, Failed to replace the node first and try to append the same node again. any one faced this issue

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

//Unable to add replaced nodes back to xml using xml slurper. Throws stackoverflow exception. Now idea how to do it

```
def xml = """<container>
                   <listofthings>
                       <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
                   </listofthings>
                 </container>"""

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    def fun = new ArrayList(root.listofthings.collect{it})
    root.listofthings.thing.each {
       it.replaceNode {}
       }
    root.listofthings.appendNode  ( { thing(id:102, name:'baz') })
    fun.each {
    root.listofthings.appendNode it
    }

    def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    String result = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield root }
    print result
```

Answer (score 0):

You call:

```
def fun = new ArrayList(root.listofthings.collect{it})
```

Which sets `fun` to be the node `<listofthings>` (and btw could be shortened to: `def fun = root.listofthings`)

Then on the line:

```
fun.each {
  root.listofthings.appendNode it
}
```

You append this node to the node `<listofthings>`.  This means your tree will be never ending (as you are attaching a node to itself), and hence the `StackOverflowException`

To get the code to run, you can change it to:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xml = """<container>
            |  <listofthings>
            |    <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
            |  </listofthings>
            |</container>""".stripMargin()

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

root.listofthings.thing*.replaceNode {}

root.listofthings.appendNode { 
  thing( id:102, name:'baz' )
}

def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String result = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield root }

print result
```

ie: get rid of the recursive node addition.

However, I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the recursive addition, so this probably doesn't do what you wanted to do...  Can you explain more what result you wanted to see?

#### Edit

I managed to get XmlParser to do what I think you were trying to do?

```
def xml = """<container>
            |  <listofthings>
            |    <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
            |  </listofthings>
            |</container>""".stripMargin()

def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def listofthings = root.find { it.name() == 'listofthings' }
def nodes = listofthings.findAll { it.name() == 'thing' }

listofthings.remove nodes

listofthings.appendNode( 'thing', [ id:102, name:'baz' ] )

nodes.each {
  listofthings.appendNode( it.name(), it.attributes(), it.value() )
}

def writer = new StringWriter()
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(root)
def result = writer.toString()

print result
```

That prints:

```
<container>
  <listofthings>
    <thing id="102" name="baz"/>
    <thing id="100" name="foo"/>
  </listofthings>
</container>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. I was able to do with XmlParser too. I was playing little bit with XmlSlurper and found that if we try to add the nodes that were already replaced then I get StackOverFlowException. I'm not sure why is it doing that?

Comment: @siva in your code you're removing the `things` from inside `listofcodes`, then adding the `listofcodes` node to itself.  You haven't removed the `listofcodes` node, so you end up with a recursive structure :-(